# How do I show the correct output when the player reaches the boss room? - Python Text Based Game

Tags: python

Yes, I have checked other posts and none of them helped me with my problem.

I have no trouble navigating between the rooms or collecting items. But when I get to the boss room regardless if I haven't collected all of the items or I have it won't show my winning or losing texts.

Also, my exit code isn't working and I'm not sure why.

```
def showinstructions():
    print('Listen!')
    print('Collect all 6 items to defeat Ganon, and save Hyrule!')
    print('---------------------------')
    print('Add item to inventory: Grab "items name" ')
    print('Move with north, south, east, and west')
    print('---------------------------')


def main():
    # Dictionary
    rooms = {
        'Skyward Sword': {'name': 'Skyward Sword', 'North': 'Majoras Mask', 'South': 'Twilight Princess',
                          'East': 'Ocarina of Time', 'West': 'A Link to the Past'},
        'Majoras Mask': {'name': 'Majoras Mask', 'item': 'Mirror Shield', 'South': 'Skyward Sword', },
        'Twilight Princess': {'name': 'Twilight Princess', 'item': 'Heros Bow', 'North': 'Skyward Sword',
                              'East': 'Breath of the Wild'},
        'Ocarina of Time': {'name': 'Ocarina of Time', 'item': 'Ocarina', 'North': 'Age of Calamity',
                            'West': 'Skyward Sword'},
        'A Link to the Past': {'name': 'A Link to the Past', 'item': 'Silver Arrow', 'East': 'Skyward Sword'},
        'Breath of the Wild': {'name': 'Breath of the Wild', 'item': 'Master Sword', 'West': 'Twilight Princess'},
        'Age of Calamity': {'name': 'Age of Calamity', 'item': 'Heart Container', 'South': 'Ocarina of time',
                            'North': 'Hyrule Warriors'},
        'Hyrule Warriors': {'name': 'Hyrule Warriors', 'South': 'Age of Calamity'}
    }

    player_move = ['North', 'South', 'East', 'West']
    inventory = []
    current_room = 'Skyward Sword'

    # Loop
    while True:

        # user input
        command = input('Where would you like to travel? ').split()
        if command[0] == 'Travel':
            if command[1] in player_move:
                open_map = rooms[current_room]
                if command[1] in open_map:
                    current_room = open_map[command[1]]
                else:
                    print('Listen! Thats the wrong way!')
            elif (command == 'Leave'):
                print('Come back soon hero')
                break

        elif command[0] == 'Grab':
            if current_room in rooms and 'item' in rooms[current_room]:  # an extra condition for check is added here
                item = rooms[current_room]['item']  # check if item is present
                if command[1] in item:
                    inventory.append(item)
                    print(item, 'stored')
                else:
                    print('Please try again')
            # When the item is unavailable in the current room
            else:
                print('Item not available in this room. Please try again.')

        print(' ')
        print('You are in {}'.format(current_room))
        print('Inventory:', inventory)
        print('---------------------------')
        open_map = rooms[current_room]
        if 'item' in open_map:
            print('Grab the {}'.format(open_map['item']))

    if current_room == 'Hyrule Warriors':
        if len(inventory) == 6:  # This is to check if the user has won
            print('You have defeated Ganon (once again), and saved Hyrule!')
            print('You are still the Hero of Hyrule')
        elif len(inventory) != 6:
            print('You have failed to collect your weapons')
            print('Ganon is still wrecking havoc on Hyrule')


showinstructions()
main()
```

I've tried making it so "Hyrule Warriors" is the only room that has the output, but I'm still getting the same outcome everytime.

Comment: `if current_room == 'Hyrule Warriors':` is not part of the `while` loop.

Comment: `elif (command == 'Leave'):` should be unindented one level and add `[0]` to `command`.

Comment: Learn basic debugging. Add print statements to track what is happening, or use a source debugger to follow the logic in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Check your indentation!

```
    # Loop
    while True:
        [...]
            elif (command == 'Leave'):
                print('Come back soon hero')
                break
        [...]

    if current_room == 'Hyrule Warriors':
        [...]
```

The check `if current_room == ...` will only be executed, after the while-loop is exited, which only happens if the user issues the command "Leave". Is this the intended behaviour?

And as @mark-tolonen pointed out in the comments, your user can checkout any time he likes, but he can never leave, as the following conditions can never both be true:

```
        if command[0] == 'Travel':
            [...]
            if (command == 'Leave'):
```